# How to evaluate Likert scale data changes over multiple surveys of the same group?

Tags: regression, anova, likert

I have five surveys of the same group of students over a semester.  Each survey uses a 5-point Likert scale.  The first and last survey contain some questions dealing with the beginning and end of the class (first impressions, final impressions), but most of the questions are identical for all four or five of the surveys.

I want to evaluate the statistical significance of changes to students' responses over time.  Unfortunately statistics is not my strong suit.  I know of the t-test, but that seems to only be applicable to two groups of data (please correct me if I'm wrong).  How should I go about evaluating this data?  Is a repeated measures one-way ANOVA appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

First, we'll need to know whether you are interested in the response to each Likert question or to a sum of Likert questions; if the latter, it matters how many questions and what the distribution of the scale looks like.

Either way, you will have to account for the nonindependence of the data, because the same people are answering the questions multiple times. Repeated measures ANOVA is one solution to this, but it makes unrealistic assumptions including sphericity, and would only be usable for the scale score, and only if the scores ranged fairly widely so that you could pretend they were continuous.

A better option is a mixed model. If you treat the scores as continuous data, then this would be a linear mixed model; if you treat them as ordinal (as you would have to do if you were interested in each question) then you would need a nonlinear mixed model.

Unfortunately, these models are not simple to implement. If you currently know only about t-tests, then you may need to hire a consultant to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two-way ANOVA before this you need to adjust your data. First add new variable name "survey" and code it 1 for first survey, and write 1 under the survey as many first survey respondents, similarly 2, 3, 4, 5. Now add columns as your first, second and so on questions. You mentioned in questions there are few extra questions in first and last survey, to handle this rescale 6-point Likert scale in second, third and fourth survey. Label 0 as "not asked in survey" other points 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 label according to the question. Run two-way ANOVA you get the desired answers.

Comment: This does not seem correct. It does not account for the fact that the data are not independent.